# In a ksh script find value of latest file/jar and save to a variable

Tags: linux, awk, ksh, rhel

I am a self-confessed beginner level when it comes to RHEL and I can navigate around, find things, run things etc. And I only have basic permissions on my DEV, INT, PROD and BCP servers at my client as most of my time is taken up in complex development.

I use ksh scripts to launch Tomcat, and for the new version of my project it is a SpringBoot launchable JAR file. New deployments will feature a dynamically changing jar/file name deployed from Nexus such that instead of the fixed name (in the older Tomcat setup for exploded folder in /webapps) I will need to look it up as it'll have a changing version number at the end.

I came up with this:

```
find . -name bondac*.jar | awk '{print substr($1,3);}'
```

Which works on CLI, so I added it to my launch ksh file (which worked previously with fixed jar name) like so:

```
jartolaunch = find . -name bondac*.jar | awk '{print substr($1,3);}'
java -jar $jartolaunch --spring.config.location=/data/chronos/activepivot/config/application.yml && sleep 1 && check_process $1
```

However this gives the error, when ksh is run, of 'jartolaunch not found'.

Comment: The jar name which will be used in the line below, so: java -jar <jar name> (which was found by the find command, and piped to awk to strip off the ./ from the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
jartolaunch = find . -name bondac*.jar | awk '{print substr($1,3);}'
```

to:

```
jartolaunch=$(find . -name bondac*.jar | awk '{print substr($1,3);}')
```

or better:

```
jartolaunch=$(find . -name bondac*.jar -printf '%P\n')
```

Comment: Yay, TYVM for your prompt answer originally in the comment :). Added to my RHEL notes for my learning! :)

Comment: Oh thanks for the cleaner no pipe second one too :)